# creating a 1. modal that pops up from a 2. button in to a 3. grid that has a 4. light box, 5. a description and a 6. href link button

Tags: button, modal-dialog, lightbox

[Noob on board. Should be looking like this. Please let me know how I can be more descriptive.Picture atached in the tittle description.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NUfl.png)

The page has a button and when clicked a modal pops up. In the modal there are a light-box grid, a text grid and a button that leads to another page. I can't use bootstrap because my code get's messy. Languages needed (HTML, CSS, JS)

1. modal that pops up from a
2. button in to a
3. grid that has a
4. light box,
5. a description and a
6. href link button

Comment: It is possible using fancybox, see example here  https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/#quick-view-1 and https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/JvGjwa But you need some CSS/JS knowledge to do the customization.

Comment: Thank you, I took a step back from that problem, I might just use a simple pop up with just one picture. If you are willing to check the code, please let me know.